# How to speedup data reaging from oracle database by PHP

Tags: php, oracle

How can I speed up generating array of 70k records from oracle database?
This code need about 10 minutes to generate array of data, to much :(
Everything is fine when i delete the second while but i need the info from this query ...

I have three tables, one of them has main ID of product and other information, second is concatenation table and third is table which has additional product information. This is a one-to-many relationship.

Any ideas?

```
$query = oci_parse($connection, '
    SELECT PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU, 
    PZG_SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA.NAZWA AS SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA,
    DATAPRZYJECIA,
    PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.IDENTYFIKATOR AS IDENTYFIKATOR,
    PZG_OSOBAINSTYTUCJA.NAZWA AS TWORCA,
    PZG_ZGLOSZENIE.IDENTYFIKATOR AS IDZGLOSZENIA,
    PZG_REJESTRPRAC.OZNACZENIEUMOWY AS OZNUMOWY,
    OZNUMOWYINNYORGAN,
    PZG_NAZWAMAT.NAZWA AS NAZWAMAT,
    PZG_POSTAC.NAZWA AS POSTAC,
    PZG_NOSNIKNIEELEKTRONICZNY.NAZWA AS NOSNIK,
    PZG_FORMATDANYCH.NAZWA AS FORMATDANYCH,
    PZG_RODZAJDOSTEPU.NAZWA AS RODZAJDOSTEPU,
    PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.OPIS,
    PZG_JEZYK.NAZWA AS JEZYK,
    PZG_TYPMATERIALU.NAZWA AS TYPMATERIALU,
    PZG_DATAOKRES.DATAOKRES AS DATAOKRES,
    OZNMATERIALUZASOBU,
    IDNADPRZEZORGAN,
    PZG_SKALA.NAZWA AS SKALA,
    PZG_UKLADODNIESIENIA.NAZWA AS UKLADODNIESIENIA,
    PZG_UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH.NAZWA AS UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH,
    PZG_DATANAKLAD.DATANAKLADU AS DATANAKLADU,
    PZG_DATANAKLAD.NAKLAD AS NAKLAD,
    NAZWAARKUSZA,
    NAZWAMATERIALU,
    PZG_KATARCHIW.NAZWA AS KATARCHIWALNA,
    PZG_DOKUMENTWYL.OPIS AS DOKUMENTWYL,
    DATAWYL,
    DATAARCHLUBBRAK                               
    FROM PZG_MATERIALZASOBU 
    LEFT JOIN PJDW_OPCJE_MATERIALZASOBU ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU = PJDW_OPCJE_MATERIALZASOBU.MATERIALZASOBU
    LEFT JOIN PJDW_KATEGORIAOPCJE ON PJDW_OPCJE_MATERIALZASOBU.KATEGORIAOPCJE = PJDW_KATEGORIAOPCJE.ID_PJDW_KATEGORIAOPCJE
    LEFT JOIN PZG_SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA = PZG_SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA.ID_PZG_SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA        
    LEFT JOIN PZG_OSOBAINSTYTUCJA ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.TWORCA = PZG_OSOBAINSTYTUCJA.ID_PZG_OSOBAINSTYTUCJA        
    LEFT JOIN PZG_ZGLOSZENIE ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.IDZGLOSZENIA = PZG_ZGLOSZENIE.ID_PZG_ZGLOSZENIE        
    LEFT JOIN PZG_REJESTRPRAC ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.OZNUMOWY = PZG_REJESTRPRAC.ID_PZG_REJESTRPRAC        
    LEFT JOIN PZG_NAZWAMAT ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.NAZWA = PZG_NAZWAMAT.ID_PZG_NAZWAMAT      
    LEFT JOIN PZG_JEZYK ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.JEZYK = PZG_JEZYK.ID_PZG_JEZYK      
    LEFT JOIN PZG_TYPMATERIALU ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.TYPMATERIALU = PZG_TYPMATERIALU.ID_PZG_TYPMATERIALU     
    LEFT JOIN PZG_POSTAC ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.POSTACMATERIALU = PZG_POSTAC.ID_PZG_POSTAC  
    LEFT JOIN PZG_NOSNIKNIEELEKTRONICZNY ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.RODZNOSNIKA = PZG_NOSNIKNIEELEKTRONICZNY.ID_PZG_NOSNIKNIEELEKTRONICZNY
    LEFT JOIN PZG_FORMATDANYCH ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.FORMATDANYCH = PZG_FORMATDANYCH.ID_PZG_FORMATDANYCH
    LEFT JOIN PZG_RODZAJDOSTEPU ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.INFODOSTEPIE = PZG_RODZAJDOSTEPU.ID_PZG_RODZAJDOSTEPU
    LEFT JOIN PZG_DATAOKRES ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.AKTUALNOSC = PZG_DATAOKRES.ID_PZG_DATAOKRES
    LEFT JOIN PZG_SKALA ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.SKALA = PZG_SKALA.ID_PZG_SKALA
    LEFT JOIN PZG_UKLADODNIESIENIA ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.UKLODNIESIENIA = PZG_UKLADODNIESIENIA.ID_PZG_UKLADODNIESIENIA
    LEFT JOIN PZG_UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.UKLWSPOLRZEDNYCH = PZG_UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH.ID_PZG_UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH
    LEFT JOIN PZG_DATANAKLAD ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.DATANAKLAD = PZG_DATANAKLAD.ID_PZG_DATANAKLAD
    LEFT JOIN PZG_KATARCHIW ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.KATARCHIWALNA = PZG_KATARCHIW.ID_PZG_KATARCHIW
    LEFT JOIN PZG_DOKUMENTWYL ON PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.DOKUMENTWYL = PZG_DOKUMENTWYL.ID_PZG_DOKUMENTWYL
    WHERE PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.DATAWYL IS NOT NULL    
    ORDER BY PZG_MATERIALZASOBU.ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU DESC
');

oci_execute($query);

$result = array();
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {

    $query1 = oci_parse($connection, '
    SELECT GODLONAZWA, POLOZENIE
    FROM PZG_GODLONAZWA_POLOZENIE
    LEFT JOIN PZG_MATERIAL_POLOZENIE ON PZG_GODLONAZWA_POLOZENIE.ID_PZG_GODLONAZWA_POLOZENIE = PZG_MATERIAL_POLOZENIE.ID_PZG_GODLONAZWA_POLOZENIE
    WHERE PZG_MATERIAL_POLOZENIE.ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU = '.$row['ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU']);
    oci_execute($query1);

    $polozenie = "";
    while (($row1 = oci_fetch_array($query1, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
        $polozenie .= $row1['GODLONAZWA']." - ".$row1['POLOZENIE'].", ";
    }
    $polozenie = substr($polozenie, 0, -2);
    if($row['DATAARCHLUBBRAK'] != ""){
        $dataArchLubBrak = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $row['DATAARCHLUBBRAK'])));
    }
    if($row['DATAWYL'] != ""){
        $dataWyl = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $row['DATAWYL'])));
    }

        array_push($result, array(
        "id"=>$row['ID_PZG_MATERIALZASOBU'],
        "sposobPozyskania"=>$row['SPOSOBPOZYSKANIA'],
        "dataPrzyjecia"=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $row['DATAPRZYJECIA']))),
        "identyfikator"=>$row['IDENTYFIKATOR'],
        "tworca"=>$row['TWORCA'],
        "idZgloszenia"=>$row['IDZGLOSZENIA'],
        "oznUmowy"=>$row['OZNUMOWY'],
        "oznUmowyInnyOrgan"=>$row['OZNUMOWYINNYORGAN'],
        "nazwaMaterialu"=>$row['NAZWAMAT'],
        "polozenieObszaru"=>$polozenie,
        "postacMaterialu"=>$row['POSTAC'],
        "nosnik"=>$row['NOSNIK'],
        "formatDanych"=>$row['FORMATDANYCH'],
        "rodzajDostepu"=>$row['RODZAJDOSTEPU'],
        "opis"=>$row['OPIS'],
        "jezyk"=>$row['JEZYK'],
        "typMaterialu"=>$row['TYPMATERIALU'],
        "aktualnosc"=>$row['DATAOKRES'],
        "oznaczenieMaterialu"=>$row['OZNMATERIALUZASOBU'],
        "idOrgan"=>$row['IDNADPRZEZORGAN'],
        "godloNazwa"=>$row['GODLONAZWA'],
        "skala"=>$row['SKALA'],
        "ukladOdniesienia"=>$row['UKLADODNIESIENIA'],
        "ukladWspolrzednych"=>$row['UKLADWSPOLRZEDNYCH'],
        "dataNaklad"=>$row['DATANAKLADU']." ".$row['NAKLAD'],
        "nazwaArkuszaSklep"=>$row['NAZWAARKUSZA'],
        "nazwaMaterialuSklep"=>$row['NAZWAMATERIALU'],
        "katArchiwalna"=>$row['KATARCHIWALNA'],
        "dokumentWyl"=>$row['DOKUMENTWYL'],
        "dataWyl"=>$dataWyl,
        "dataArch"=>$dataArchLubBrak
    ));
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for a **minimal** example of your problem; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and your expected output. You have a multiple page SQL query which joins over 20 tables and then you use a loop with further nested queries to get extra data (of course its slow) but it would be easier to understand if you reduced the example in the question to only a couple of tables and explained the logic.

Comment: Why use queries in a loop? Why not use `LISTAGG` in the first query to generate the concatenated strings in the database and then you don't have to have the second query. Also, don't use string concatenation to build queries; use bind variables and then the database won't need to re-parse the query.

Comment: Tune the SQL optimizer plan, and also move some of the logic from PHP to the query.  Tune the network (e.g. SDU size).  Tune the 'prefetch' value to optimize internal buffers for fetching rows, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-prefetch.php.  Note the cases that this won't help: e.g. when fetching LONGs or LOBs.

Comment: Please do not say you have 3 tables, then produce a 21 table join. Then compound it with application code introducing  additional tables. Then complain it is slow.